# How to change the font size of label in the forms of dynamics crm?

Tags: forms, label, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

after hunting a lot didn't find any mean to change the font size of label of a form in dynamics CRM. So, let me ask from the forum of expert to suggest me the better way to do so. 
that is How can I change the font size of labels in dynamics CRM's form?

Help and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a link where someone had a similar question and the answer confirmed my suspicion that yes it is possible but there is no supported way of doing it. I copied the answer below.

**Hi,
is possible to change the font size on a form header, but of course is an unsupported modification.
you need to add this code on your OnLoad event:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-crm-Field-Label-Print');
for (var i=0; i<labels.length; i++) 
{
labels[i].style.fontSize = '14pt';
}
var values = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-crm-Field-Data-Print');
for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++)
{
values[i].style.fontSize = '14pt';
}
```

this code will change also the footer size, is possible to change only the header, but you need to check the parent tree to find if you are inside the header or inside the footer.
Is also possible to do these things with jQuery, but I prefer simple JavaScript to avoid load the library.**

Comment: And the link:  http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d9b7a83-06e5-41f8-b0ff-bc7cb963cc4f/edit-form-header-font-size?forum=crmdevelopment

Comment: Your suspicion is right :) no supported way to change the font size but manipulating the DOM using JavaScript it's possible.